# How to get the data points of a particular bin in a weighted histogram?

Tags: python, histogram, binning, weighted-graph

I have a weighted histogram in python and I like to have all the data point of a particular bin.

I use this to plot the histogram:

```
c,n,x=plt.hist(e, bins=50,  range=(-500, -400), weights=p, color='blue')
```

`e` and `p` both have 130k data points.
I like to get all the data points of a particular bin (lets say bit at -450).

Comment: What are c, n, and x?

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this:

```
c,n,x=plt.hist(e, bins=50,  range=(-500, -400), weights=p, color='blue')
ind = np.where(n == -450)[0][0]
print(c[ind])
```

Example:

```
np.random.seed(0)

#data
mu = -450  # mean of distribution
sigma = 50  # standard deviation of distribution
x = mu + sigma * np.random.randn(10000)

num_bins = 50

# the histogram of the data
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(x, num_bins, density=True,  range=(-500, -400))

ind = np.where(bins == -450)[0][0]
print(n[ind])
```

Output->

```
0.011885780547905494
```

Hope, this may help!